# Why it takes 30 mins (too slow) to run a pretrained model by tensorflow in my laptop but 1 second in other desktop?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a question with load and use pretrained model by kereas, tensorflow.

It's a .h5 to load and use, but it takes half hour to get the result in my laptop. But in other desktop, it can get result in 1 second! Do you know what's wrong with my laptop or what should I modify settings to run it?

Comment: Need more details - are both versions of TF the same? What are the specs of your machines?

Comment: Yes, both are TF 2.0, my laptop: memory is 16 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3, processor is 2.4 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5. I use python3.7 of anaconda3 spyder; other desktop use python in linux system.

Comment: Still need more info; what are your CUDA, cuDNN versions? What are the GPUs, if they use any? Do you use the same input data format? Also don't forget @OverLordGoldDragon (or other username) when replying, to notify; I don't have to do it as you're auto-subscribed to your own question